# How to remove the FC layer off of a fine turned model keras

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence

So I have finetuned a Resnet50 model with the following architecture:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(resnet)
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(736, activation='softmax')) # Output layer
```

So now I have a saved model (.h5) which I want to use as input into another model. But I don't want the last layer. I would normally do it like this with a base resnet50 model:

```
def base_model():
    resnet = resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
    x = resnet.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda  x_: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    return Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=x)
```

but that does not work for the model as it gives me an error. I am trying it like this right now but still, it does not work.

```
def base_model():
    resnet = load_model("../Models/fine_tuned_model/fine_tuned_resnet50.h5")
    x = resnet.layers.pop()
    #resnet = resnet50.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)
    #x = resnet.output
    #x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda  x_: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    return Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=x)
enhanced_resent = base_model()
```

This is the error that it gives me.

```
Layer dense_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000001C61E68E2E8>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

I don't know if I can do this or not.

Comment: What error do you get for the code block where you use `resnet.output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured it out after quitting for an hour. So this is how you will do it.

```
def base_model():
    resnet = load_model("../Models/fine_tuned_model/42-0.85.h5")
    x = resnet.layers[-2].output
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name="FC1")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6, name="FCDrop1")(x)
    x = Dense(4096, activation='relu', name="FC2")(x)
    x = Dropout(0.6, name="FCDrop2")(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda  x_: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    return Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=x)
enhanced_resent = base_model()
```

And this works perfectly. I hope this helps out someone else as I have never seen this done in any tutorial before.

```
x = resnet.layers[-2].output
```

This will get the layer you want, but you need to know which index the layer you want is at. -2 is the 2nd to last FC layer that I wanted as I wanted the feature extractions, not the final classification. This can be found doing a

```
model.summary()
```